# Where can I get python-gtkhtml2?

Tags: installation, python, software-center

I am trying to install ultamatix and it says I need python-gtkhtml2 and it isn't in the software center and it wasn't found in a search in terminal (*sudo apt-get install python-gtkhtml2*).  How can I find this package without downloading it from the internet with a virus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the creator of ultamatix aka TheeMahn.  I highly suggest installation of [themelinux's repository](http://www.themelinux.com/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=13) as it is much more maintained & has been [repomastered](http://forumubuntusoftware.info/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=5692).  It has all libraries necessary to run it & the most current version.  Well, minus natty which I am working on currently.  That is how I found this thread ;)

Comment: Thanks TheeMahn.  I love your OS, but my computer is a bit slow and isn't really good for your amazing OS.

Comment: I am using Natty so I'll wait until you've fixed it up.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this depends upon which version of ubuntu you are using (answer copied from [here](http://www.absolutelytech.com/tag/python-gtkhtml2/)):

For lucid, download the appropriate Karmic .deb package from originally from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic-updates/python-gtkhtml2) but now in the official archives [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-python-extras/) and install it i.e. amd64 is 64bit ubuntu, whereas i386 is 32bit ubuntu.

For maverick users, you’ll have to download and install libgtkhtml2-0 package from the following [site](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libgtkhtml2-0) to solve the dependency issue of python-gtkhtml2.

Comment: Ok I tried that and for some reason it didn't work, but thank you for trying.

Answer (score 1):

That prior answer was wrong.  The package that is necessary is found at the following http://downloadue.info/repo/

Comment: Hi Sam - apologies.  Should have remembered that karmic is not supported.  All the packages have moved to the official archives.  I've edited my original answer to reflect this.  Note your link is not to an official archive, hence (in your original question) may contain stuff you may not want to install...